# Migrating from Model First to Code First, some breaking changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This code worked fine when I used model first aproach. And stoped saving a Vote if it is a `new Vote()`. I guess model first generated classes used some 'magic' on property setters i thought that's what we put `virtual` in code first properties for.  Is there a way to make it work old style? or should i search and replace and tie a new object to graph in some other way?

```
public ActionResult Vote(int id, string votetype)
{
    int userid = ViewBag.User.Id;
    var pub = DB.Publications.Single(p => p.Id == id);
    var votes = pub.Votes.SingleOrDefault(v => v.MemberId == userid) ??
                new Vote
                {
                     MemberId = userid,
                     Publication = pub
                 };
    DB.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Full", new { id = id });
}
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Especially why `SaveChanges`? You just query entities from the DB but do not change anything nor add you a new entity to the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked before but it was written in a bad way from the beginning because it really uses some internal magic and in your example it can be called side effect. You should avoid code which does some logic through side effects.

The magic is automatic fix up of navigation properties. You create a new `Vote` and set its `Publication` navigation property with `Publication` instance attached to the context. In such case EF will fix relations for you and it internally also adds `Vote` to `Publication`. Because of the fix up the new `Vote` will become tracked as well (as a new entity).

Your custom classes used in the code first doesn't have fix up methods unless you write it manually or copy them from code generated by POCO T4 template used in model and database first. Without fix up the new `Vote` will not be added to the context and `SaveChanges` will not perform any modification.

Use @Diego's code to fix your method.

Comment: Nice explanation. I hadn't used EF before code-first and didn't know about the fixup magic.

Comment: @Diego: In case of POCO it is a code template will generate for you and it causes quite a lot issues especially when combined with lazy loading because fix up can trigger lazy loading on opposite navigation property.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere in that code are you telling EF to persist the new vote.

Change the line where you get/create the vote to:

```
var vote = pub.Votes.SingleOrDefault(v => v.MemberId == userid);
if (vote == null)
    pub.Votes.Add(new Vote
                  {
                      MemberId = userid,
                      Publication = pub
                  });
```